# Show yestearday and old 30 days instead date laravel

Tags: php, laravel, date

is there a way to display in bales instead of yesterday or older than 30 days? forget how I did it for yesterday but it doesn't work.

```
@elseif (Carbon\Carbon::parse($ns->created_at)->toDateString() === date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 day')))
```

It should have been displayed to me yesterday for this condition but it does not display. And for 30 days I would do the same

Comment: `created_at` is already a Carbon object, so you can check `$ns->created_at->isYesterday()`

Comment: @AbdullahAlNoor That won't work, you're calling `whereDate()` on a Carbon instance.. :)

Comment: Doesn`t work. But for "today" is works

Comment: You don't need to compare it to anything... `Carbon::today()` returns a carbon instance of today, `yesterday()` returns a carbon instance of yesterday -- but `isToday()` and `isYesterday()` are methods called on the instance, and returns a *boolean*. So your entire code in your question becomes `@elseif ($ns->created_at->isYesterday())`

Comment: [Read the manual](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this via [diffForHumans](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-humandiff) function provide by Carbon.

Since the *created_at* field is a carbon instance, you can achieve this by doing

```
$ns->created_at->diffForHumans()
```